# Using NEW.* inside EXECUTE regarding psql

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I checked all related questions on SO but none helped in my case.
I have 2 loops(outside for the tables and  inside for the columns). Tables are represented by 'r', and columns by 'm'.  While being inside the 'm' loop  which is supposed to send column values to the to-be-created trigger function. When I try to use 'NEW.m' (with trying many different formatting attempts) compiler always gives error.
Can you kindly advice on it please? Br

```
FOR r IN SELECT table_name   FROM information_schema.tables  LOOP 
 FOR m IN SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE (table_name = r.table_name )  LOOP                                                                               
function_name := 'dictionary_functions_foreach_trigger';





   EXECUTE format('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %s()
   RETURNS trigger AS
   $BODY$
   DECLARE

   BEGIN
        IF NEW.m IS NOT NULL AND NEW.m IN  (SELECT key FROM tableX.tableX_key)       
     THEN  RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
   END;

   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
   COST 100;
   ALTER FUNCTION %s()
   OWNER TO mydb;',function_name,  function_name);  



     EXECUTE 'CREATE  TRIGGER ' || function_name || ' BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE  ON '  || belonging_to_schema || '.' || r.table_name || ' FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ' || function_name || '();';
```

[image: new error while trying to update for individual columns]

----Trigger Functions after edit-

```
 EXECUTE format(
        
  'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %s()
   RETURNS trigger AS
   $BODY$
   DECLARE
      insideIs text := %s ;
     
   BEGIN
         
         FOR %s IN 0..(TG_NARGS-1) LOOP
            IF %I= TG_ARGV[%s]
            THEN insideIs := %s ;     
             END IF;
         END LOOP; 
     
     
        IF NEW.%I IS NOT NULL AND   (insideIs =%s) AND  NEW.%I IN  (SELECT key FROM tableX.tableX_key)       
        THEN  RETURN NEW;
        ELSE             RETURN OLD;              
        END IF;
       
     END;
   $BODY$  
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
   ALTER FUNCTION %s()
   OWNER TO mydb;' , function_name,  'notInside',   'i' ,  m.column_name,  'i' , 'ok',    m.column_name,    'ok',     m.column_name ,function_name);
```

Comment: Please add full query and error description

Comment: Why don't you just setup a foreign key constraint instead of creating a trigger? Does the table on which the trigger is then used actually **have** a column named `m`?

Comment: Hi, i edited question. I am using 2 loops and trying to get values from the inner loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another placeholder for the column name, they way you have written it, the column name `"m"` is hardcoded in the function.

You also don't really need the outer loop, as the `table_name` is also available in `information_schema.columns`.

Your trigger would also fail with a runtime error if the condition is not true as you don't have a `return` in that case. If you want to abort the statement, use `return null;`

You should also use `format()` for the `create trigger` statement.

```sql
FOR m IN SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name 
         FROM information_schema.columns 
         WHERE table_name in (...) 
LOOP                                                                               
  function_name := 'dictionary_functions_foreach_trigger';
  EXECUTE format('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %I()
    RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.%I IS NOT NULL AND NEW.%I IN  (SELECT key FROM tableX.tableX_key) THEN  
          RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN null; --<< you need some kind of return here!
   END;
   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
   COST 100;
   ALTER FUNCTION %s()
   OWNER TO mydb;', function_name, m.column_name, m.column_name, function_name,  function_name);  

  EXECUTE format('CREATE TRIGGER %I BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON %I.%I FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE %I()', 
                  function_name, m.table_schema, m.table_name, function_name);
END LOOP;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cc307c18701d24026277688579aa15f4)

Comment: thank you for the great points ahwnn, but if I am not terribly wrong, it still gives error as:                                              ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "m"
LINE 20:        OWNER TO mydb;' , m.column_name, m.column_name,f...

Comment: @mears: sounds as if you are not using `m` as the record variable in the FOR loop then.

Comment: when I add as  "RAISE INFO USING MESSAGE = 'column name   is : ' ||  m ; "
I can see that column name comes correctly from 'm'. I just cant use it inside the EXECUTE I guess:/

Comment: There is no `FROM m` inside the function body.

Comment: Thank you, you are right ,now I changed 'm' to Record type.. But still the same error persists, I couldn't get it why indeed

Comment: @mears: in the first `format()` I forgot to include the `function_name`. See my edit

Comment: thanks big indeed, but argument numbers not matching after your edit. can you check again pease?

Comment: after I do as below I got no more error. But it does not update when new insertion done somehow! EXECUTE format('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %s()
   RETURNS trigger AS
   $BODY$
   DECLARE

   BEGIN
        IF NEW.%s IS NOT NULL AND NEW.%s  IN  (SELECT key FROM tableX.tableX_key)       
      
         THEN  RETURN NEW;
      END IF;
   RETURN OLD; 
   END;
   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
   COST 100;
   ALTER FUNCTION %s()
   OWNER TO mastercif;' , function_name,  m.column_name, m.column_name, function_name);

Comment: When I put   NEW.gender   (gender is an example column name) instead of                                                                                                   using NEW.%s    +     'm.column_name'  while formatting   works strangely.

Comment: Please read my code. It should be `NEW.%I` to deal with identifiers, not `%s`

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but when I pass things as: %s %I %I %s    , function not doing its function. When I put as  %I  %I  %I  %I    it even gives error.   Right now the only configuration that worked was hardcoding (as for example:  NEW.gender)

Comment: Well, I have shown you a working example. You need to figure out what your code does differently.

Comment: thank you ahwnn  it worked, s not giving error on it anymore! Only issue now is while I'm inserting a column, trigger is fired for every column regarding that  table, thus making it impossible to change value for the intended column only. Do you have an idea about that maybe? All day working on it still not working. (I updated the question with the EXECUTE function for creating each trigger functions)

Comment: @mears: you can restrict the trigger to specific columns with a [when condition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

Comment: Thank you, I tried something like the below but not had luck till now with it. I am doing something wrong for sure:      EXECUTE 'CREATE TRIGGER ' || function_name || ' BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ' || m.column_name || ' ON ' || belongs_to_schema || '.' || r.table_name || ' FOR EACH ROW WHEN '|| NEW.column_name|| '=' ||  m.column_name || ' EXECUTE PROCEDURE ' || function_name || '();';